# How do I use session variables across multiple sub-domains?

Tags: php, session, dns

I have been losing my session variables rather consistently when I click on the link from our websites notification email. After breaking my head for a long time on this, I today realized that www.domain-name.com does not contain the session variables while domain-name.com does!!

Why does this happen? And what do I do to set things right(php-apache)?

Comment: Thanks All for helping me with the problem! This is what I added to my .htaccess file to make domain.com get redirected to www.domain.com
    
    `Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
    rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`

Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to redirect with .htaccess file:**

http://papermashup.com/useful-htaccess-techniques/

http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#red2

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are based on cookies, which are per-domain.
`www.domain.com` is a different domain than `domain.com`, so their cookies are kept separate.

Standard practice is to choose one variant and `301` redirect the other variant to the preferred one.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense as to why I've been losing the session! :)

Answer (score 2):

The session ID is stored in a cookie, and in the cookie can be specified how it should react over domain names.

Take a look at PHP's [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) documentation.

You can change PHP's session cookie configuration with:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".mydomain.com");
```

Comment: Thanks Nican! Just briefly went through the setcookie documentation. Will read more! When you mean ".mydomain.com" does that encompass all the subdomains of domain.com(including http://www.domain.com and http://domain.com)?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing technically special about ‘www’. The domain ‘domain.com’ is distinct from ‘www.domain.com’; if you want to associate them, that needs to be explicit somewhere, usually in the HTTP server configuration.

Comment: Thanks Bignose! Would making www.domain.com point to domain.com help solve the issue quick? I am not too much of a server guy, and more of a programmer. But would love to learn to fix it the right way!